# create new html elements for button click in query

Tags: jquery, html

when i click submit button,some new html elements will have to add and display the text what i entered in text-box. my code is below:

```
$('#myButton2').on('click', function (event) {
      $('input:text').each(function(index){
      if (index==0) {
        $('body').append("<div id='inner' class='one'>");
        $('.one').append("<Section id='inner1'>");
        $("<input type='radio' value='' />")
     .attr("id", "myfieldid")
     .attr("name", "check-1")
     .attr("style", "display:none;")
     .appendTo(".one");
        $('.one').append("<label for='check-1' style='font-size:10pt;color:#000000;'>"+$(this).attr('value'));

       }
});
});
```

for first click,the output displayed once.but at second click,i got output twice and so on.
i got output like:

```
  //for first click
    one
  //for second click
    one
    two
    two
    .
    .
    .
```

but i want like this:

```
//for first click
    one
  //for second click
    one
    two

    .
    .
    .
```

anyone help me?

Comment: can you show us the html output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the liberty of changing the code not to use `each` method (I hope it's ok), and to add the labels and radio buttons in to a section. Also I made the id attributes to unique with an integer.

```js
$(function () {
    $('#myButton2').on('click', function (event) {
        var input = $('input:text').val();
        var count = $('#inner label').length;
        //if div inner doesn't exist
        if ($('#inner').length == 0) {
            $('body').append("<div id='inner' class='one'>");
            $('.one').append("<Section id='inner1'>");
            //add to section inner1
            $("<input type='radio' value='' />")
                .attr("id", "myfield-1")
                .attr("name", "check-1")
                .attr("style", "display:none;")
                .appendTo("#inner1");
            //add to section inner1
            $('#inner1').append("<label for='myfield-1' style='font-size:10pt;color:#000000;'>" + input);

        } else {
            count = count + 1;
            $('.one').append("<Section id='inner" + count + "'>");
            var innerId = "#inner" + count;
            $("<input type='radio' value='' />")
                .attr("id", "myfield-" + count)
                .attr("name", "check-1") // same name for radio button group
            .attr("style", "display:none;")
                .appendTo(innerId);
            $(innerId).append("<label for='myfield-" + count + "' style='font-size:10pt;color:#000000;'>" + input);

        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myButton2">Add</button>
<input type="text" />
```